# how to add textfield into bootstrap panel with styles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I try to create responsive web page using bootstrap. I apply a panel.But when I adding Textfiled Its hasn`t any styles which in my[image] the sample code.

This is my panel code.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading"><i class="icon-bar"></i><b>Order Item</b></div>
          <div class="panel-body">

              <div class = "row">
                <div class ="span6" >
                   <label align= "text-center">First Name</label>
                   <input type="text" class="span6" align= "text-center" placeholder="Your First Name">
                   <label align= "text-center">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="span6" align= "text-center" placeholder="Your First Name">
                </div>
               </div>
             <div class ="row">

                <h4 class="muted text-center">Reach Us to best computer system</h4>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and it is working for me.  Check for any **css overriding**.  Are you sure that you're including the following components?

1. **`jQuery` library**
2. Bootstrap.css
3. Bootstrap.js

[image]

check out this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JdDt7/)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML and inputs seem to be styled correctly by Bootstrap on this page: http://innovastudio.com/BootstrapLiveEditor/index.html

You may need to nest the inputs in a `<form></form>` tag, but they should be styled without.

Are any other input styles overriding or more specific than Bootstrap's?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap 3 or 2? I am using the 2.3.2 CDN, no js and **[this result](http://cdpn.io/CyiGw)** is what I get. The fields work fine but I don't get the panel. Are you using bootstrap 3.[image]